# Место сокола - в небе. Тире?

Tags: тире

Место сокола - в небе. Правильно ли оформлено предложение? По какой причине здесь необходимо тире?

Comment: @Maria, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Тире здесь замещает подразумеваемое "находится" и обозначает соотв. речевую паузу. Написание без тире воспринимается как заголовок - как будто за этим последует уточнение координат (в каком месте неба находится сокол).

Answer (score 1):

Место сОкола - в небе.

Эллиптическое предложение вида "подлежащее - обстоятельство". Тире/пауза ставится, если логическое ударение падает на подлежащее.

Для сравнения: место сокола в нЕбе, а место человека на землЕ. Место сОкола - в небе, место человЕка - на земле.